# Error wrapping WebView within VStack: Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate

Tags: webview, swiftui

I was trying to wrap my custom struct WebView within VStack but got this error:

> Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate

WebView is such a struct:

```
struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var request: URLRequest

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        return WKWebView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.load(request)
    }

}
```

And this is part of my ContentView:

```
                        ZStack{
                            ScrollView{

                                VStack(spacing:0){
                                    ZStack{

                                        ZStack (alignment: .leading){...}.offset(y: self.expandedScreen_shown ? 0 : 0)
                                            .clipped()
                                            .background(Color.white)
                                            .foregroundColor(Color.green)
                                            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                                        VStack (alignment: .leading){...}.frame(height: self.maxHeight)
                                    .zIndex(1)

                                    WebView(request: URLRequest(url: URL(String: "google.com")))


                                    Rectangle()
                                        .fill(Color.white)
                                        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)

                                }

                            }
                            .frame(width: self.expandedScreen_startPoint.width, height: self.expandedScreen_startPoint.height)
                            .background(Color.clear)
                            .cornerRadius(self.expandedScreen_shown ? 0 : 15 )
                            .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.3))
                            .offset(x: self.expandedScreen_startPoint.minX, y: self.expandedScreen_startPoint.minY)

                            // ScrollView ends

                            Button(action: {...}){...}.offset(x: (UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2) - 30, y: (-1 * UIScreen.main.bounds.height/2) + 60)
                        }
                            // ZStack ends
```

As I have seen projects successfully wrap this WebView within a VStack, I cannot find where the problem is here. More generally, what is the difference between "complex closure return type" and "explicit type"?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things I noticed regarding your WebView.

1) String should be string, and

2) the URL should be unwrapped

try this:

```
WebView(request: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://google.com")!))
```

Comment: Thanks! I ran into a new problem that the entire WebView does not show up. Should I wrap it with some other view? The WebView used to work inside of NavigationView, but it is not wanted for this project. Currently, this entire ZStack is an invisible part of another ZStack, and it will become visible following a tap gesture.

Comment: did my answer fix your error? If so, please mark the answer as correct.

As for the other questions, it's difficult to say without all the info, but typically you shouldn't have to wrap WebView in another view for it to work. I recommend you breakdown your code into small chunks, rather than all in the same ZStack.

Comment: if the web page does not show up try prefixing with  https://